# mysql report join tables and Database structure issue

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, database-schema

I'm trying to achieve the following report result:

```
campaign_name   visits  leads   registrations
3333              3       0         0
direct            3       2         1
(null)            0       1         1
test              0       1         1
```

I have this database structure and I'm quite sure now that the relationships are incorrect. I played around with joining them but I am doing it wrong by
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/451de/7

Your advise would be appreciated.

Comment: problem is with your date  for tracking is like (5,26, 50 tracked on April month)  while related entry to other table like leads have different date

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mysql_query("select  campaign_name  , count(t.id) 
             as visits, count(l.id) as leads ,count(r.id) as registrations

from trackings t

left join leads as l
 on l.tracking_id =t.id

left join registrations as r
 on r.tracking_id =t.id

where t.created_at between '2015-04-01' AND '2015-05-31' and t.aff_id =5

group by campaign_name");
```

Comment: Er Sonveer Singh I tried it but the date range in your query  is incorrect  should be between : between '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-31 and your query returned the same result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/451de/23

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
SELECT `campaign_name`, 
   count(t.id) as visits, 
   count(l.id) as leads ,
   count(r.id) as registrations

FROM `trackings` t

   LEFT JOIN leads l ON t.`id` = l.`tracking_id` 
   LEFT JOIN registrations r ON t.`id` = r.`tracking_id`

WHERE t.created_at between '2015-04-01'
      AND '2015-05-31' 
      AND t.aff_id =5

GROUP BY `campaign_name`

ORDER BY visits DESC
```

not what you are looking for because of date issue.
trackings table
id

```
6           2015-04-07 18:54:57
26          2015-04-13 11:06:13
50          2015-04-20 14:42:23
```

while leads

```
26         2015-05-13 11:07:09
50         2015-05-20 14:43:07
```

Comment: I believe I need to change my DB structure, is it a polymorphic relationship? If so how should I approach it? the result should be http://pastie.org/private/bu38tbqvv2jl0ooujaoua . get all actions per campaign per date range independently.

Comment: Polymorphic relationship is best approach to handle complex structure. Have separate table for registration,leads and tracking and then create other related table lead_tracking, registration_tracking

Comment: assumming the db structure you recommend how would the query for the result look like?